# what swift concept is .overlay and body

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm following a [basic swift guide](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views)
but I'm struggling to understand this block of code:

```swift
struct CircleImage: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("turtlerock")
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay {
                Circle().stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 4)
            }
    }
}
```

specifically, what kind of swift concept/data structure is used in `.overlay {}`
and `var body: some View {}`
I've searched through the swift documentation and couldn't find related concepts.

Comment: actually overlay should be with regular parentheses  as `.overaly( view here )`, ie. it is a function which accepts one argument confirming to View protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `.overlay { ... }` is a call of a method `overlay` with a closure argument, using [trailing closure syntax](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102)
- `some View` is an [opaque result type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html)
- SwiftUI view bodies use [result builders](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0289-result-builders.md), in particular [ViewBuilder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder).

Comment: @ malhal I rolled back your edit, because I think it’s important to first and foremost explain that this is a method call in regular old swift. A “view modifier” is not a thing as far as the language is concerned, I.e.you won’t find it mentioned anywhere on The Swift Programming Language book. It’s merely a pattern in SwiftUI.